# Redirect a URL to Include a ? that is Missing

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

How do I replace a url (in an htaccess file) like this:
http://example.com/linkName

With this:
http://example.com/?linkName

I also want to make sure that links like this are unaffected:
http://example.com/redirect.php?linkName

I can't quite figure out the regular expression.

Comment: Thanks to @user1215106 I've got a few regular expressions that perform the right replacement, but the redirect is still not working.

Answer (score 2):

For any directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/|)(.*)$ $1?$2 [L,QSA]
```

This will redirect http://mysite.com/dir/linkName to http://mysite.com/dir/?linkName

---

For root directory only:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(/?)(.*)$ $1?$2 [L,QSA]
```

This will redirect http://mysite.com/dir/linkName to http://mysite.com/?dir/linkName

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. It's causing an internal server error.

Comment: @JustinPutney - Code in the answer is just a part of the configuration. Do you have experience with `.htaccess`? Did you turn on rewrite engine by `RewriteEngine on` command? Check documentation at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html and google for tutorial(s) and example(s) to learn more. Also check log files to find out what exactly is going on, why the error occured.

Comment: I have a little bit of experience and I have other working redirects in my .htaccess file. I've checked several examples. For some reason, the error doesn't seem to be logged anywhere.

Comment: @JustinPutney - Did you check error log file? You can also try to add another line between: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$` to see if that helps. I didn't test my code and maybe rewrite is in loop without another condition.

Comment: I wondered about the infinite loop. That line did not fix it, unfortunately. There's no error log in that directory, even when I refresh, and no errors in the root directory.

Comment: OK, found a central error log in my cpanel. Here's the error:
.htaccess: RewriteRule: cannot compile regular expression '^(/?)(.*/|)(.*)$'\n

Comment: @JustinPutney - Some servers require the usage of `RewriteBase /`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12950/discussion-between-justin-putney-and-user1215106)